# Getting Inf/-Inf error when plotting valid/non-missing data in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot quarter circles

```
N = 1E1
# set of radiuses 
r = c(1,2,3,4)

# plot quarter-circles
plot(0,0)
for (i in 1:length(r)) {

  quadX <- seq(from = 0,to = r[i],length.out = N) # 
  print(quadX)
  quadY <- sqrt(r[i]^2 - quadX^2) 
  print(quadY)

  p1 <- points(quadX,quadY)
}
plot(p1)
```

gives confusing error

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Any help would be apreciated before I go insane just before Xmas...

Comment: Change the initial plot's boundaries to see what's happening: `plot(0,0,xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(-5,5))`

Comment: @ErrorJordan is spot on here. Plus, `p1` is `NULL`, so neither `plot(p1)` nor `print(p1)` will help you

Comment: All you need is the code you have, **minus the last line**, if you attend to plot limits like @ErrorJordan says